# Trait's type member requires to be Send

Tags: rust, async-await, traits, generic-programming, type-safety

I have two traits: `Processor` and `Persist`. The first one is responsible for processing some entity, the second one is for ***asynchronous*** persisting the processed entity.

Given the two traits I want to implement the `trait ProcessPersist` taking care of both processing and persisting. Here is how it looks like and ***compiles fine***

```
use async_trait::*;

trait Processor<T>{
    type Output: Send;  // <----------------------- Note Send here

    fn process(&self, t: T) -> Self::Output;
}

#[async_trait]
trait Persist<T>{
    async fn persist(&self, t: T) -> Result<(), ()>;
}

#[async_trait]
trait ProcessPersist<T>{
    async fn process_persist(&self, t: T) -> Result<(), ()>;
}

#[async_trait]
impl<T, M> ProcessPersist<T> for M
where
    T: Send + 'static,
    M: Processor<T> + Send + Sync,
    M: Persist<<M as Processor<T>>::Output>
{
    async fn process_persist(&self, t: T) -> Result<(), ()> {
        let out = self.process(t);
        self.persist(out).await
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:** The thing that I'm trying to avoid is to remove the context bound `type Output: Send` because this looks too restrictive. Instead, I'd like it to be specified in the `trait ProcessPersist` implementation somehow.

Is it possible to do?

Simply removing `Send` from the type `Output` ***does not compile***:

```
use async_trait::*;

trait Processor<T>{
    type Output;  // <----------------------- Send is removed

    fn process(&self, t: T) -> Self::Output;
}

#[async_trait]
trait Persist<T>{
    async fn persist(&self, t: T) -> Result<(), ()>;
}

#[async_trait]
trait ProcessPersist<T>{
    async fn process_persist(&self, t: T) -> Result<(), ()>;
}

#[async_trait]
impl<T, M> ProcessPersist<T> for M
where
    T: Send + 'static,
    M: Processor<T> + Send + Sync,
    M: Persist<<M as Processor<T>>::Output>
{
    async fn process_persist(&self, t: T) -> Result<(), ()> {
        let out = self.process(t);
        self.persist(out).await
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:47:61
   |
47 |       async fn process_persist(&self, t: T) -> Result<(), ()> {
   |  _____________________________________________________________^
48 | |         let out = self.process(t);
49 | |         self.persist(out).await
50 | |     }
   | |_____^ future returned by `__process_persist` is not `Send`
   |
   = help: within `impl core::future::future::Future`, the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `<M as Processor<T>>::Output`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
  --> src/main.rs:49:9
   |
48 |         let out = self.process(t);
   |             --- has type `<M as Processor<T>>::Output` which is not `Send`
49 |         self.persist(out).await
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ await occurs here, with `out` maybe used later
50 |     }
   |     - `out` is later dropped here
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn core::future::future::Future<Output = std::result::Result<(), ()>> + std::marker::Send`
```

Comment: [The duplicate applied here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8e335befceaed06ff1663af8b1d4fc59): just add `M::Output: Send` to the `where` clause.

Comment: @trentcl Exactly, thanks much.